# MapRoute configuration error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dictionary, routes, nullable

The configuration of my MapRoute, do like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
 name: "EquipamentosTrafego",
 url: "Equipamentos/{cidadecod}/{contratocod}/Trafego/{filtro}",
 defaults: new
 {
    controller = "Equipamentos",
    action = "EquipamentosTrafego"
 }
 );
```

And in my view I try to access that way:

```
<td align="center">
<div class="list-group-item">
     <a href="/Equipamentos/@item.cidadecod/@item.contratocod/Trafego/OFF">
           <span class="badge" style="font-size: 18px; background-color:@item.totaleqpson_stts">@item.totaleqpson</span>
     </a>
</div>
```

The following error is returned to me:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter
>   'numerodeserie' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Equipamento(System.String, System.String,
>   Int32, Int32)' in 'SCO.Controllers.EquipamentosController'

How to solve?

Comment: Can you please update your code for action method?

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult EquipamentosTrafego(string cidadecod, string contratocod, string filtro)
        {
            List<object> DadosCidades = new List<object>();
            var consultaEquipamentos = new EquipamentosModel();
            var consultaCidadesContrato = new EquipamentosContratosModel();

            ViewBag.DadosEquipamentos = consultaEquipamentos.ListaTrafego(cidadecod, contratocod, filtro);
            ViewBag.DadosCidades = consultaCidadesContrato.ListaPorContrato(cidadecod, contratocod);
            ViewBag.cidadecod = cidadecod;
            if (filtro == "OK")
            {
                ViewBag.mensagem = "Todos os Equipamentos com Registro de Tráfego acima ou igual a "+ @Math.Round(ViewBag.parametrosPorcentagem.PorcMediaTrf, 0) + "% da média para o Horário.";
            }
            else if(filtro == "NOK")
            {
                ViewBag.mensagem = "Todos os Equipamentos com Registro de Tráfego abaixo de " + @Math.Round(ViewBag.parametrosPorcentagem.PorcMediaTrf, 0) + "% da média para o Horário.";
            }

            return View("Equipamentos");
        } // EquipamentosTrafego
```